# Android push notifications when app is killed

Tags: android, push-notification

I have the task of finding out how to prevent newer android devices from killing the app which then will no longer be able to send local push notifications.. is there a way to do it ? I've heard of GMS.. any good ?

Scenario:
User has a meeting in 21 days and one day before it he wants to get a notification. 
This should be stored locally, no server thing I guess. ?

Thanks

Update:
Best Link: https://en.proft.me/2017/05/7/scheduling-operations-alarmmanager-android/

Comment: hi , follow this link , hope it's will help
https://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/

Comment: It seems like you are talking about system `Notification` rather than push because you say it must be local. The "push" part of "push notification" means it is being sent from the server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Push Notifications after App is killed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42477483/push-notifications-after-app-is-killed)

Answer (score 1):

For push notifications you should use FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging), GCM is deprecated and passed away.

FCM allows you to handle a messages, even if app is killed.

There are [two types of messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive) in FCM, notification and data messages. Data messages are always processed by your app, notification can be handled automatically, if app is killed.

But you should use `WorkManager` or `JobScheduler` or something similar to schedule your job, because `FirebaseMessagingService` will be killed soon after receiving message.

Comment: even locally ? Just store them on device no server-thing. For example set a timer like in 3 weeks device has to fire an notification and store that event locally, will it do that after long time app was closed

Comment: @GambitPlayer_3 For scheduling local events you can use [`AlarmManager`](https://www.google.com/search?q=alarmmanager&oq=AlarmMaang&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.2527j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8])

Comment: Thank you ! But note that there is an issue with API 19+ concerning the OS restricting a bit..